# unable to scroll table in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm load an array of dictionary in a table view and after reload my table I called a method which change the data of dictionary from array and then refresh/reload particular index of tableview. But I'm not able to scroll my table until unless my complete data not updated again.

Code from where I call my method and reload table:

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    [Hud hideAnimated:true];
    [self.myTbl reloadData];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
         [self loadTutorials];
    });
}
```

method in which I'm trying to update my table data.

```
#pragma mark:GetAllData
-(void)loadTutorials{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{


    int k = 0;

  for (NSMutableString*linknew in linkArr) {
     //here some calculations code for parsing then next  
      for (TFHppleElement *elements in contributorsNodes) {
        // 5
        for (TFHppleElement *child in elements.children) {
            if ([child.tagName isEqualToString:@"img"]) {
                // 7
                @try {
                    NSString*url = [child.attributes objectForKey:@"src"];

                    NSMutableDictionary*dict = [[feeds objectAtIndex:k] mutableCopy];
                    [dict setObject:url forKey:@"image"];
                    [feeds removeObjectAtIndex:k];
                    [feeds insertObject:dict atIndex:k];

                    NSIndexPath*index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:k inSection:0];

                    [self.myTbl reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[index] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];


                }
                @catch (NSException *e) {}
            }
        }
    }k++;
  }
  });
}
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel*lbl = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    UIImageView*imgView = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:103];


    [imgView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.jpg"]];

    lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I assume you `disptch_async` because the processing of data takes long time - if so it doesn’t make sense to dispatch this work onto the main queue - you will be blocking the main thread nevertheless. You should dispatch your work onto a background queue and then dispatch parts related to UI updates onto the main queue.

Comment: @ Losiowaty Thanks for reply. I put method  [self.myTbl reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[index] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
 in disptch_async and remove disptch_async from starting of my method but still same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have many things in your question make me confused.

- With `parserDidEndDocument` method, I don't know why you need to call `[self.myTbl reloadData]` although after that you update `self.myTbl` inside `loadTutorials` method.
- Why do you need to call 2 `dispatch_async` here, both outside and inside `loadTutorials` method? I think it's not necessary. Just call 1 time.
- To replace an object in an array, you don't need to remove and insert object. Just replace by using `feeds[k] = dict`. Make sure `feeds.count > k` before using.
- As i guess, you use `try catch` because you got crash when updating `self.myTbl` inside `loadTutorials` method. In my opinion, you should use `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` instead of `try catch`.

I think the problem is because you used `try catch` to handle crash.

Try to rewrite you code with background queue as @Losiowaty suggested, we will have

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
  [Hud hideAnimated:true];
  [self.myTbl reloadData];
  [self loadTutorials];
}



#pragma mark:GetAllData
-(void)loadTutorials{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    int k = 0;

    for (NSMutableString*linknew in linkArr) {
      //here some calculations code for parsing then next
      for (TFHppleElement *elements in contributorsNodes) {
        // 5
        for (TFHppleElement *child in elements.children) {
          if ([child.tagName isEqualToString:@"img"]) {
            NSString*url = [child.attributes objectForKey:@"src"];

            // I assume in some case, feeds[k] doesn't exist. We need add an
            // NSMutableDictionary to this index before using to avoid crash.
            // If you make sure feeds[k] always exist you can ignore it

            if (feeds.count == k) {
              [feeds addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]];
            }
            [feeds[k] setObject:url forKey:@"image"];

            NSIndexPath*index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:k inSection:0];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
              [self.myTbl beginUpdates];
              [self.myTbl reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[index] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
              [self.myTbl endUpdates];
            });
          }
        }
      }k++;
    }
  });
}
```

Let try the code first. If you still have any problem, let me know. I will help you.

Comment: I stored parsed data in array and after end of document  method call parserDidEndDocument and to set these stored data into table I reload my table next is in my parsed data i'm not getting image so I hit method loadTutorials from it I'm getting my image and I  update my array and refreshing particular cell. I tried your code still same issue.Thanks for reply.

Comment: my table view display when I reload my Table first at method parserDidEndDocument after that it will stuck and when all images updated by method loadTutorials it will show image and I'm able to scroll.

Comment: Understand. Can you show me `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method? I want to see how did you load image from url. Maybe the problem is the way you load image

Comment: I used tag value and to upload image I used sdWebImage third party library.

Comment: It looks good. I have updated my answer with using background queue as @Losiowaty suggested. Please try again and tell me what happens.